# Basics about producer-consumer

Tags: linux, synchronization, kernel

I have to improve a Linux Kernel work (`struct work_struct`) that processes data.
Data is written into a list by another thread and read from the list by the work. List operations are protected with a `spin_lock` so the list can't be mixed up.
The thread adds data, then calls `schedule_work` that either runs the work or does nothing when it detects it is already running.
The work reads until the list is empty, then quits.

That looks ok except in the rare case when

1. Work finds no more data in the list and decides to terminate.
2. At the same time the thread adds data to the list and calls `schedule_work` but work is still active so nothing happens.
3. Work quits and data in the list is not processed anymore.

What would be the recommended way to synchronize this better?

I wonder if I can use that `work` or I better use a normal thread that waits on a semaphore.
That thread would always be "there" but on the other hand the work that is used now is somehow "there" as well so that wouldn't make any difference, would it?

Regarding the processing thread or work be "there" all the time while most of the time it's unused, I would also be happy if I could let it terminate when it's done and safely recreate it in all circumstances from the inserting thread.
Atomic variables would help me do that, but I an unsure whether that is too much overload.
Should I better let that one thread exist and wait to be activated now and then, or terminate it?

Comment: You could call `schedule_work` under the same spinlock-protected section, where you find that the list of data is empty. That way the race you describe will be impossible. Similarly, a thread which adds data to the list could call `schedule_work` (in the spinlock-protected section too).

Comment: @Tsyvarev The empty list is discovered inside the work. Calling `schedule_work` there wouldn't have any effect in my understanding. The thread that adds data does call `schedule_work` as you suggest, but this is what would lead to the problem I explained. Can you explain your solutions a bit more or give an example?

Comment: "... then calls `schedule_work` that either runs the work or does nothing when it detects it is already running." - The words "runs" and "running" are not quite correct here. The function `schedule_work` **schedules** the work to be executed in the **future**. Once *execution* of a scheduled work starts,  the work is no longer treated as *scheduled*. So a call to `schedule_work` will schedule the work again. That is, a work may call `schedule_work` for itself, and this call will have an effect. Other thread may re-schedule the work by calling `schedule_work` even if the work near the end.

Comment: Sounds interesting, then I will have to learn more about that, perhaps I only got it wrong.